Plotting curves of diode current against temperature
I have done I-V measurement at different temperatures on a diode, now I am trying to plot the $I_D$ vs temperature curve but varying $\eta$ (the ideality factor). I am not sure of the procedure though. Should I upload all my $I_D$ vs $V_D$ data for the temperatures I have, define $I_D = A*T^2 \exp(-φ_b /KT)(\exp[V_D/ηV_T]-1)$, change $\eta$ from 1 to 2 with 0.05 step, and hope I get an $I_D$ vs $T$ curve? Does this seem correct?

Could you please use MathJax to type the formulas? As is, the equations are not very clear.
